# Nested Insert-Exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert-into

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Errors: “INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.” and “Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement.” How to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795263/errors-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-and-cannot-use-the-rollback-s)

We have a sproc in production which returns a selection. This selection is populated by an INSERT INTO to a temp table, calling a sproc.

So now we now need to produce another sproc, which will be using the data returned by sproc_1.
The problem is that the new sproc also contains a temp table, which is populated by calling sproc_1.

Obviously we get the SQL error complaining about nested insert-exec.

Any ideas how to get past this?
We have spent a day researching the problem, not finding a **working** solution.

Comment: Check   [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40748787/3573705)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you would be able to achieve nested insert exec
References :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/e66c9e71-4424-4cf3-920c-6725ffc40162/
But I guess this might help you
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic13595-8-1.aspx#bm68301