# Insert into temptable from stored procedure having ouput variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

```
create table #TagsTable ([StandardDeviation] nvarchar,
    [AffectedPing] nvarchar,
    [AffectedPingPercentage] nvarchar,
    [BaselineDataPointsCount] nvarchar)


DECLARE @IsAlert Bit
insert into #TagsTable
EXEC ProcessPingErrorAlert_SingleRow
 @AlterId = 1,
 @Hour = 1,
 @Day = '2016-02-02',
 @TraceId = 1583,
 @IsAlert = @IsAlert OUTPUT


select * from #TagsTable
```

Error:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

When I remove the output variable from the stored procedure, it works. How can I insert into temp table from stored procedure having output variable?

Procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessPingErrorAlert_SingleRow] --1 ,12,'2015-12-08',1    
    (@AlterId  INT,  
     @Hour     INT,  
     @Day      DATE,  
     @TraceId  INT,  
     @IsAlert  BIT OUTPUT)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED    

    DECLARE @AlertType VARCHAR(250)       
    DECLARE @BaselineId INT      
    DECLARE @DatasetId INT      
    DECLARE @DatasetCount INT      
    DECLARE @AlertThresholdCount INT      
    DECLARE @PingErrorDatasetHourCount INT    

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 AlertId  
                  FROM Alert  
                  WHERE AlertId = @AlterId  
                    AND ACTIVE = 1  
                    AND IsDeleted = 0)  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR ('Alert not found.', 16, 1);  
        RETURN;  
    END  

    SELECT @AlertType = Code  
    FROM AlertType a  
    JOIN Alert b ON a.AlertTypeId = b.AlertTypeId  
    WHERE b.AlertId = @AlterId  
      AND a.Code = 'PingErrors'  

    IF @AlertType IS NULL  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR ('Invalid alert type.', 16, 1);  
        RETURN;  
    END  

    SELECT @BaselineId = a.BaselineId  
    FROM BaselineConfiguration a  
    JOIN BaselineType b ON a.BaselineTypeId = b.Id  
    JOIN AlertBaseline c ON a.BaselineId = c.BaselineId  
    WHERE b.Code = 'PingErrorHourly'  
      AND c.AlertId = @AlterId  
      AND a.Active = 1  
      AND a.IsDeleted = 0  

    IF @BaselineId IS NULL  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR ('Baseline not found.', 16, 1);  
        RETURN;  
    END  

    SELECT @DatasetId = Id  
    FROM BaselineDatasetSetting  
    WHERE BaseLineId = @BaselineId  
      AND IsCalculated = 1  

    IF @DatasetId IS NULL  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR ('Baseline dataset not found.', 16, 1);  
        RETURN;  
 END  

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#PingErrorDataset') IS NOT NULL  
 BEGIN  
     DROP TABLE #PingErrorDataset  
 END;        
 CREATE TABLE #PingErrorDataset  
 (  
  [BaselineId]    [int] NOT NULL,  
  [Day]           [datetime] NOT NULL,  
  [Hour]          [tinyint] NOT NULL,  
  [PingCount]     [int] NOT NULL,  
  [ErrorCount]    [int] NOT NULL,  
  [ErrorRatio]    [float] NOT NULL,  
  [RefreshLogId]  [int] NOT NULL  
 )      
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[#PingErrorDataset]  
   (  
     [BaselineId],  
     [Day],  
     [Hour],  
     [PingCount],  
     [ErrorCount],  
     [ErrorRatio],  
     [RefreshLogId]  
   )  
 SELECT ped.[BaselineId],  
        ped.[Day],  
        ped.[Hour],  
        ped.[PingCount],  
        ped.[ErrorCount],  
        ped.[ErrorRatio],  
        ped.[RefreshLogId]  
 FROM   [dbo].[PingErrorDataset] ped  
 WHERE  ped.[BaselineId] = @BaselineId  
        AND ped.[Day] < @Day  
        AND ped.[Hour] = @Hour     

 SELECT @DatasetCount = COUNT(*)  
 FROM   [#PingErrorDataset]  

 IF @DatasetCount IS NULL  
    OR @DatasetCount = 0  
 BEGIN  
     RAISERROR ('No data found in the baseline dataset.', 16, 1);   
     RETURN;  
 END      

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#AlertThreshold') IS NOT NULL  
 BEGIN  
     DROP TABLE #AlertThreshold  
 END;       
 CREATE TABLE #AlertThreshold  
 (  
  [AlertId]         [int] NOT NULL,  
  [ThresholdId]     [int] NOT NULL,  
  [ThresholdValue]  [varchar](250) NOT NULL,  
  [OperatorId]      [int] NOT NULL,  
  [ThresholdType]   VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,  
  [ThresholdCode]   VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,  
  [Operator]        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL  
 )      

 INSERT INTO #AlertThreshold  
   (  
     [AlertId],  
     [ThresholdId],  
     [ThresholdValue],  
     [OperatorId],  
     [ThresholdType],  
     [ThresholdCode],  
     [Operator]  
   )  
 SELECT a.AlertId,  
        a.ThresholdId,  
        a.ThresholdValue,  
        a.OperatorId,  
        b.ThresholdType,  
        b.Code,  
        c.Operator  
 FROM   AlertThreshold a  
        JOIN Threshold b  
             ON  a.ThresholdId = b.ThresholdId  
        JOIN ComparisonOperator c  
             ON  a.OperatorId = c.OperatorId  
 WHERE  a.AlertId = @AlterId      

 SELECT @AlertThresholdCount = COUNT(*)  
 FROM   [#AlertThreshold]  

 IF @AlertThresholdCount IS NULL  
    OR @AlertThresholdCount = 0  
 BEGIN  
     RAISERROR ('No Threshold found for the alert.', 16, 1);   
     RETURN;  
 END      

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#PingErrorDatasetHour') IS NOT NULL  
 BEGIN  
     DROP TABLE #PingErrorDatasetHour  
 END;        
 CREATE TABLE #PingErrorDatasetHour  
 (  
  [BaselineId]  [int] NOT NULL,  
  [Day]         [datetime] NOT NULL,  
  [Hour]        [tinyint] NOT NULL,  
  [PingCount]   [int] NOT NULL,  
  [ErrorCount]  [int] NOT NULL,  
  [ErrorRatio]  [float] NOT NULL  
 )      

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[#PingErrorDatasetHour]  
   (  
     [BaselineId],  
     [Day],  
     [Hour],  
     [PingCount],  
     [ErrorCount],  
     [ErrorRatio]  
   )  
 EXEC [CalculatePingErrorRatio] @BaselineId,  
      @Day,  
      @Hour    

 SELECT @PingErrorDatasetHourCount = COUNT(*)  
 FROM   [#PingErrorDatasetHour]      

 IF @PingErrorDatasetHourCount IS NULL  
    OR @PingErrorDatasetHourCount = 0  
 BEGIN  
     RAISERROR ('No data found for the hour specified.', 16, 1);   
     RETURN;  
 END      


 DECLARE @ErrorRatio DECIMAL      
 DECLARE @AveragePingErrorRatio DECIMAL      
 DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000) = ''      
 DECLARE @PingErrorRatioStandardDeviation FLOAT      
 DECLARE @SDThresholdValue INT      
 DECLARE @PingErrorRatioSDValue DECIMAL      
 DECLARE @SDOperator VARCHAR(50)      

 DECLARE @APThresholdValue INT      
 DECLARE @APOperator VARCHAR(50)      
 DECLARE @AffectedPings INT      

 DECLARE @APPThresholdValue INT      
 DECLARE @APPOperator VARCHAR(50)   
 -- Getting actual values of PingCount, PingErrorRatio, AffectedPings and ServiceName  
 SELECT @ErrorRatio = ErrorRatio,  
        @AffectedPings = ErrorCount  
 FROM   [#PingErrorDatasetHour]  
 WHERE  [Day] = @Day  
        AND [Hour] = @Hour   

 --Getting Average and Standard Deviation of PingErrorRatio from baseline data against given day and hour  
 SELECT @AveragePingErrorRatio = AVG(ErrorRatio),  
        @PingErrorRatioStandardDeviation = STDEVP(ErrorRatio)  
 FROM   [#PingErrorDataset]  
 WHERE  [Day] < @Day  
        AND [Hour] = @Hour   

 -- Calculation of PingErrorRatio StandardValue  
 --Formula = (PingErrorRatio of current hour - AveragePingErrorRatio from baseline dataset) / PingErrorRatioStandardDeviation of baseline dataset  
 IF EXISTS (  
        SELECT TOP 1 *  
        FROM   #AlertThreshold  
        WHERE  ThresholdCode = 'SD'  
    )  
 BEGIN  
     SELECT @SDThresholdValue = CAST(ThresholdValue AS INT),  
            @SDOperator = Operator  
     FROM   #AlertThreshold  
     WHERE  ThresholdCode = 'SD'  

     SET @PingErrorRatioSDValue = (@ErrorRatio - @AveragePingErrorRatio) / @PingErrorRatioStandardDeviation        
     SET @Query += CAST(@PingErrorRatioSDValue AS VARCHAR(250)) + ' ' + @SDOperator   
         + ' ' + CAST(@SDThresholdValue AS VARCHAR(250))  
 END  
 -- Getting AffectedPings threshold value  
 IF EXISTS (  
        SELECT TOP 1 *  
        FROM   #AlertThreshold  
        WHERE  ThresholdCode = 'AP'  
    )  
 BEGIN  
     SELECT @APThresholdValue = CAST(ThresholdValue AS INT),  
            @APOperator = Operator  
     FROM   #AlertThreshold  
     WHERE  ThresholdCode = 'AP'      

     IF LEN(@Query) > 1  
     BEGIN  
         SET @Query += ' AND '  
     END  

     SET @Query += CAST(@AffectedPings AS VARCHAR(250)) + ' ' + @APOperator +  
         ' ' + CAST(@APThresholdValue AS VARCHAR(250))  
 END  
 -- Getting AffectedPingPercentage threshold value  
 IF EXISTS (  
        SELECT TOP 1 *  
        FROM   #AlertThreshold  
        WHERE  ThresholdCode = 'APP'  
    )  
 BEGIN  
     SELECT @APPThresholdValue = CAST(ThresholdValue AS INT),  
            @APPOperator = Operator  
     FROM   #AlertThreshold  
     WHERE  ThresholdCode = 'APP'  

     IF LEN(@Query) > 1  
     BEGIN  
         SET @Query += ' AND '  
     END  

     SET @Query += CAST(@ErrorRatio AS VARCHAR(250)) + ' ' + @APPOperator +  
         ' ' + CAST(@APPThresholdValue AS VARCHAR(250))  
 END  

 IF LEN(@Query) > 1  
 BEGIN  
     SET @Query = 'IF ' + @Query +  
         ' BEGIN  SELECT @IsAlert=1 END ELSE BEGIN SELECT @IsAlert=0 END'  
 END      

 DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)      
 SET @ParmDefinition = N'@IsAlert BIT OUTPUT'   
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query,@ParmDefinition,@IsAlert = @IsAlert OUTPUT    

 IF @IsAlert = 1  
 BEGIN  
     INSERT INTO PingErrorAlertData  
     SELECT [BaselineId],  
            [Day],  
            [Hour],  
            [PingCount],  
            [ErrorCount],  
            [ErrorRatio],  
            @TraceId AS TraceId,  
            @IsAlert AS IsAlertHour  
     FROM   #PingErrorDatasetHour   
     UNION ALL  
     SELECT [BaselineId],  
            [Day],  
            [Hour],  
            [PingCount],  
            [ErrorCount],  
            [ErrorRatio],  
            @TraceId AS TraceId,  
            0 AS IsAlertHour  
     FROM   #PingErrorDataset  
 END  
 SELECT @PingErrorRatioSDValue AS StandardDeviation,   
   @AffectedPings AS AffectedPing,  
   @ErrorRatio AS AffectedPingPercentage,  
   @DatasetCount AS BaselineDataPointsCount  
END
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Running your error message through my favorite search engine turned up [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795263/errors-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-and-cannot-use-the-rollback-s) on StackOverflow: *"A restriction in SQL Server is you can only have one INSERT-EXEC active at a time."*. Verify whether that is the case.

Comment: I'm wondering what's the idea behind the scenes on using an output parameter if at the end we are reading the table just created, I think we can embed the result of the output parameter into the table #TagsTable and get the results we want from it or apply the different validations using the result of the #TagsTable instead of using the output value

Answer (score 1):

Inserting into table from a stored proc having output variable works.please run below code  .

```
alter proc usp_getdates
(
@id int,
@count int output
)
as
begin
select @id
union all
select @id as 't'

select @count=@@rowcount

end


--insert part
declare @count int
insert into #tt
exec usp_getdates
@id=1,
@count =@count out
```

I am not getting any error,the error should be from your stored proc as it says EXEC cant be nested.It may be not possible to say until seeing your proc code

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

```
insert into  #TagsTable
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','server=DB\CYBERREPORTING;Trusted_Connection=yes','SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;declare @isAlert bit; EXEC MonitoringDB.dbo.ProcessPingErrorAlert_SingleRow 1,1,''2016-02-02'',1583,@IsAlert = @isAlert output')
```