# An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested. Dealing with error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Not duplicate. The problem here is it has different structure. and I have some restrictions of what I can change and what I can't. Here I have exact example, which other tickets don't. OPENROWSET cannot be applied either, because test1 loops through all dbs (`using       EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql)`. And I can't use it, because in OPENROWSET you have to specify from which db you are running procedure

Suppose I have these two SPs:

```
create procedure test1
@ProcName  varchar(155)
as
begin

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#testt') is not null drop table #testt
create table #testt1(a int, b int)

insert #testt1
exec @ProcName

select * from #testt1
end

create procedure test2  
as
begin

declare @sql varchar(155)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#testt2') is not null drop table #testt2
create table #testt2(a int, b int)

select @sql = 'select 1 as a,2 as b'

insert #testt2
exec (@sql)

select * from #testt2

end
```

when I run `exec test1 @ProcName = 'Test2'`, it returns error:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

The problem here is that I can't stop using `insert exec` in `test2`. And test1 should have @ProcName as a variable

What is the least painless way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors: "INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested." and "Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement." How to solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795263/errors-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-and-cannot-use-the-rollback-s)

Comment: @JacobH, not duplicate. The problem here is it has different structure. and I have some restrictions of what I can change and what I can't. Here I have exact example, which other tickets don't

Comment: Well every problem has a different structure. Have you tried using OPENROWSET that was recommended in the link I posted?

Comment: @JacobH, that can't be applied. Updating ticket with reason

Comment: Removed bold since it may sound like shouting

Comment: I agree with @JacobH - this is a duplicate. Author does not write why he need insert...exec. There are many ways how to share data between procedures, not `OPENROWSET` only

Comment: @MikhailLobanov, I made it easy and simple in above representation. But here are details: I can't stop using insert exec in test2, because I use there many variables in a query, which I attach and detach, and then manipulate that temp table.

Comment: @Sher have you read that article? You write about `OPENROWSET` in your question, but there are another ways to deal with this problem

Comment: @MikhailLobanov, I did. Nothing helped. At least from my point of view. That is the reason why I'm posting question here.

Comment: @Sher What problem you have with Process-Keyed Tables? You cannot rewrite your procedures?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov, I know community rules, and I try to follow them. You think that I didn't research well, I did. If you are going to post here unconstructive and unrelated critique, please, just leave this page

Comment: @Sher I think what you are looking for may not exist. Your best options have been suggested (temp table, TVP, OPENROWSET and OPENQUERY, etc.) Maybe try using a non-temporary table? Your next step is probably a CLR if *none* of these options work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `insert` statement inside test2 procedure solved problem

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the temporary table in the second procedure with a table variable, then use OPENQUERY (as explained in http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html), like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE Database1
CREATE DATABASE Database2
GO
DECLARE @ProcedureTest2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ProcedureTest2='create procedure test2  
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON 

declare @sql varchar(155)

DECLARE @testt2 TABLE (a int, b int)

select @sql = ''select 1 as a,2 as b''

insert @testt2
exec (@sql)

select * from @testt2

end'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL='USE Database1 EXEC('''+REPLACE(@ProcedureTest2,'''','''''')+''')'
EXEC(@SQL)
SET @SQL='USE Database2 EXEC('''+REPLACE(@ProcedureTest2,'''','''''')+''')'
EXEC(@SQL)

GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'LOCALSERVER',  @srvproduct = '', @provider = 'SQLOLEDB', @datasrc = @@servername

GO
CREATE procedure test1
@ProcName  varchar(155)
as
begin

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#testt1') is not null drop table #testt1
create table #testt1(a int, b int)

DECLARE @Databases TABLE (DBName sysname PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @Databases VALUES ('Database1')
INSERT INTO @Databases VALUES ('Database2')

DECLARE Databases CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT * FROM @Databases d

DECLARE @DBName sysname
OPEN Databases

WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM Databases INTO @DBName
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 BREAK

    DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(500), @SQL2 NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @SQL1='EXEC '+QUOTENAME(@DBName)+'.dbo.'+QUOTENAME(@ProcName)
    SET @SQL2='SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LOCALSERVER, '+QUOTENAME(@SQL1,'''')+')'

    PRINT @SQL2
    INSERT INTO #testt1
    EXEC (@SQL2)
END

CLOSE Databases
DEALLOCATE Databases

select * from #testt1
end

GO
--EXEC [Database1].dbo.[test2]

--SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LOCALSERVER, 'EXEC [Database1].dbo.[test2]')

EXEC dbo.test1 'test2'

GO
EXEC sp_dropserver 'LOCALSERVER'
DROP PROCEDURE test1
DROP DATABASE Database1
DROP DATABASE Database2
```