# Executing multiple sub stored procedures in a master stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using multiple stored procedures (return type tabular only 1 row in result)  in a master stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MAster_sp]
    (@param INT) 
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[sp1] @param 
    EXEC [dbo].[sp2] @param
    .
    .
END
```

Then output is like this

sp1 output:

```
Male_Emp_Count       Female_Emp_Count 
--------------      ---------------- 
1                    0
```

Sp2 output:

```
empId               empJoiningDate                            
-----------         --------------
17                  2019-07-10
```

.
.
.

I want these results in single dataset row as a response to my API.

When I tried inserting into a table variable, I get an error

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

What is this error and how to handle this error? I tried google but no relevant article or info that helps me to understand this issue.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MAster_sp]
    (@param INT) 
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tempMainTbl 
    (
          c1 INT NULL,
          c2 INT NULL,
          c3 INT NULL,
          c4 INT NULL,
          c5 INT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #tempMainTbl (c1, c2, c3)
        EXEC [dbo].[sp1] @param 

    EXEC [dbo].[sp2] @param
    .
    .

    SELECT * from #tempMainTbl 
END
```

Error:

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.[sp1], Line 33 [Batch Start Line 8]
>   An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Actual result that I got now:

sp1 Output

```
Male_Emp_Count Female_Emp_Count 
-------------- ---------------- 
1              0
```

Sp2 Output

```
empId       empJoiningDate                            
----------- --------------
17          2019-07-10
```

Expected result:

```
Male_Emp_Count       Female_Emp_Count     empId      empJoiningDate                                
--------------       ----------------     -----      --------------
1                     0                    17         2019-07-10
```

All stored procedures output in single row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested. Dealing with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051283/an-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-dealing-with-error)

Comment: Tag correctly - code is generally always specific to the database engine. Presumably you are using SQL Server. And make an effort - searching the internet for that specific error message will find many discussions.

Comment: @SMor i tag correctly still not figure out the problem, i'll check your tagged question for better reference, thanks Smor for your valuable comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue has to do with having a stored procedure with a *insert into*, being called by another stored procedure that does the *insert into*.

The only solution really is to merger the procedures.

Here's what you probably have right now:
MAster_sp:

```
INSERT INTO #tempMainTbl (c1,c2,c3)
EXEC [dbo].[sp1] @param
```

sp1:

```
Insert into #someothertemptable
exec someotherprocedure @param
```

You just can't do that unfortunately in SQL server. Here's why and a work around:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-resolve-an-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-errorproblem

Here's the a similar question in a different post:
[Errors: "INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested." and "Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement." How to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795263/errors-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-and-cannot-use-the-rollback-s)

Comment: thanks, now i can better understand the problem. (y)