# Run parallel transaction while executing code in another session

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2016

Is there any possibility to run update at some specific point of time, but in different/parallel session? In the provided example I want some specific update to be run at the time when I run `WAITFOR`. Currently I have this `WAITFOR` block to have some time to switch to another SSMS (or other tool) window/tab and run update while it's waiting for 10 secs. Logically the only thing is needed to be done, is that transaction started at this point of time.

```
EXEC dbo.p_sync_from_accounts_ext_test @enable_snapshot_isolation = 1
                                     , @run_update_flag = NULL
                                     , @run_wait_for_10 = NULL
                                     , @acc = @acc;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'; -- Execute update in parallel transaction
-- table update should be performed in that parallel transaction

EXEC dbo.p_finish_sync_attributes;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10858305/11683?

Comment: No, stored procedures, nested EXEC statements have nothing to do with that question

Comment: Read the answer, not the question. `FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;', ...)`

Comment: I've tried to put UPDATE statement using `OPENROWSET` before `WAITFOR DELAY` statement and the result was the same as if I was using normal UPDATE. I understand that there is lack of info, I'll try to provide more info about the exact task/problem I'm trying to solve. To be short, it is related to the `rowversion` values, generated during update with combination of the temporal tables' interval columns values.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, have you been able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

**Method 1:** [loop-back linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#managing-linked-server-definitions) (linked server that points to your current server) that does not have DTC enabled. Call your SP from your linked server.

**Methd 2:** create an SQL Server Job and [start the job programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

Note that in the first case your update statement must be included in an SP. In the second case it is advisable but not necessary.

Comment: I wasn't able to do that with loop-back linked server (DTC disabled). Executing it with job surely helped