# Nested Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

How can i insert values of a nested stored procedure into a table.
For example if i created a stored procedure like this.

```
    Create procedure New
    begin
        create table #tmp
        (
            id int,
            name varchar(50)
        );

        insert into #tmp
            exec stored_procedure 1,2;

        insert into #tmp
            exec stored_procedure 1,2;
        select * from #tmp
    end
```

Now if I execute this command, SQL Server will display error:

```
insert into #table
    exec New;
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Please share

Comment: And if you search on that error - which you did not include - you will find many discussions about the error and possible solutions. Erland has extensive discussion about "sharing" generally [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Answer (score 1):

Right now you’re not returning any data from your procedure `New`. If you want it to return data for your calling code to insert you’ll need a `select` statement in it.

Eg add a line at the end:

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp;
```

Also, you can’t nest INSERT EXEC statements. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795413/8479) for more details

Comment: i added that statement as well but sql server give this error,INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

Comment: Ah, you’re right, you can’t nest `INSERT EXEC`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795413/8479

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a insert with de values returned by a Stored Procedure.

In your case the easiest way is to change de stored procedures by table functions.
[You can find more about table functions here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/)

My opinion is to make it simple if u can.